# Why don't the phases common to rows or columns in the Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa matrix matter?

Tags: standard-model

As the tittle says, I want to know why don't the phases common to rows or columns in the Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa matrix matter?